# Is there any method to remotely create ceph rgw user?

Tags: amazon-s3, ceph, radosgw

As you know, we can create a ceph rgw user by command `"radosgw-admin user create"`, but we can only execute this command in the shell of ceph environment. So, Is there any method to remotely create ceph rgw user? For example, by restful api.

Comment: You asked for a REST API, which I linked to, and yet you accepted a Java tool that uses the same API I linked to?

Comment: sorry, not familiar with "accepted", I wanted both of your answers to be "accepted", but it seems that only one option can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an an Admin REST API, and it does have a [create-user operation](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/jewel/radosgw/adminops/#create-user).

```
PUT /{admin}/user?format=json HTTP/1.1
Host: {fqdn}

(json-payload)
```

It uses the same S3 authentication, just with extra permissions granted to the user, so look for one of the clients that can let you do that, such as [RGWAdmin](https://github.com/UMIACS/rgwadmin)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [radosgw-admin4j](https://github.com/twonote/radosgw-admin4j) if you are a Java user.